# TypeScript: How to reference internal.Writable in basic-ftp NodeJS module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

In [basic-ftp module API docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp) I read:

```
downloadTo(writableStream | localPath, remotePath, startAt = 0): Promise<FTPResponse>
```

But when I have the module linked to a TypeScript project, I read:

```
(method) Client.downloadTo(destination: string | internal.Writable, fromRemotePath: string, startAt?: number | undefined): Promise<bf.FTPResponse>
```

So, while I have type `WritableStream` in TypeScript (with `@types/node` at least), I don't have (for arguably obvious reasons) the `internal.Writable` type.

I am trying to wrap this in a "helper" method (just to simplify the tasks in my particular application), with something like this:

```
function get(file: string, contents : WritableStream) : boolean {
  if (!connected()) {
    log_err("Attempt to get() without an active FTP connection.");
  }
  ftp_client.downloadTo(contents, file);
}
```

Then to the call of `downloadTo()` I get the message from IntelliSense:

```
Argument of type 'WritableStream<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Writable'.
```

What am I missing here? While I expect not to be able to just "implicitly cast" from `WritableStream` to `internal.Writable`, I am not sure where to point.

Some versions I am using:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╗
║    Software ║ Version ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╣
║         TSC ║ 3.8.3   ║
║      NodeJS ║ 12.16.2 ║
║         NPM ║ 6.14.4  ║
║ @types/node ║ 13.11.1 ║
║   basic-ftp ║ 4.5.4   ║
║  Windows 10 ║ 1903    ║
║      VSCode ║ 1.44.2  ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was missing:

```
import { Writable } from "stream";
```

Found that out by inspecting basic-ftp's [src/Client.ts file](https://github.com/patrickjuchli/basic-ftp/blob/master/src/Client.ts#L3) (or just local `Client.d.ts` one).